# Reducing vert/triangle/whatever else count before exporting into Unity?

Tags: mesh, vertices, unity, optimization

Question is basically in the title, what should I do to remove everything what basically can't be seen and etc without reducing quality of the outside of the mesh - what will be seen?

Do I have to be smart and make mesh "optimized" on my own right from the start or can I reduce those counts in some ways in case I didn't think about it at all(especially when I don't even know what in meshes causes lag)?

Comment: Difficult to answer this : of course if some parts of the mesh are never seen, delete it. But the polycount depends a lot of the role of the mesh in your game. Is it a main character (almost always seen) or a secondary one (seen few seconds, or in far background) ? Is it a very often used part of the decor ? I think the first point is to consider the gamer point of view : what will focus his eye. Also, maybe you'll need to care about the whole scene weight on the cpu/gpu (so not only one mesh)... hope this (a bit broad) comment can help.

Comment: Okay, so I shouldn't make the level basically one mesh, and if it's big enough, I should also divide it and make some loading points just like, for example, portal(game) does? Is that what you mean?

Also I meant something that would delete vertices automatically, for example I made low poly (style, not actually so "low poly") tree, which is "snowy", but it has a scaled down copy of itself with different material, put inside of it, so a lot of vertices just take up space in it, but I don't quite know how to delete vertices without breaking things.

Comment: I don't know Unity, so I can talk about general things only. So I don't know if Unity allow only 'portal leveling' or is able to stream continuously the parts to load. Concerning decreasing the polycount, yes you can low poly your model using the decimate modifier (have a try, that may correspond or not to what you want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience you should not pay too much account on the number of vertices  in a mesh. What really slows down unity is the number of [draw calls](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OptimizingGraphicsPerformance.html) caused by using too many materials in a scene.

When you have more than 10K vertices of an object you might want to consider creating less detailed objects and use them with [level of detail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_detail).

Comment: That makes sense.

Is there any easy way to "ruin" object by keeping it's shape but decreasing it's detail significantly without recreating a less detailed object? I don't think I would have too many problems recreating same thing like 4 times (or whatever many depending on what transition I would want), but I am more of programmer than modeller so I don't really know how to make a good replication of something but with less details. (to make something resemble original object from far away while close up it's just basically nonsense)

Comment: Blender provides a *decimate modifier* https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/decimate.html which does the tedious part for you.